# Enki JS Exercise

Tags: javascript

```
Function greet!(name)
{
    this.name = name!;
    this.superpowers! = {
        hello!: function!() 
        {
            console.log('hello there')
        }
    }
}

const flash = new Superhero('Flash')
Flash.superpowers.greet()
```

Everything with an explanation mark after the name is something I've chosen (e.g., greet!)

I'm trying to get acquainted with JS and this Enki app is a quick walkthrough/cheat sheet. This solution seems right to me (drag and drop words) but it's not correct. Please help, I've googled functions and naming conventions and can't see where my error is

Comment: where is Superhero class, what is Flash(F starts with capital) i think you are missing the Superhero class and instead fof Flash.superpowers it should be flash.greet.hello. also function decleration why you need ! negation character

Comment: The ! just means these are words I added

Comment: please check the answer and let me know if anything else to be added or any doubts you have. And please let me know what you are trying to achieve so it will be helpful to answer  your expected solution and we can close the question

Comment: Did you try running the code (without the exclamation marks)? The error messages from the interpreter should tell you where you need to redo the choice.

Comment: Hi @JosephMather, the name of the function should be `Superhero`, not `greet` :) (disclaimer, I work at Enki). You can also see the solutions in our OSS repo, [here's your particular question](https://github.com/enkidevs/curriculum/blob/master/javascript/core/objects/object-part-2.md#practice) where the top 5 words in the list below the code indicate the answers to replace the `???`, in the order of top-down and left-right.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying like this? See the below snippet

```js
class Superhero{
  constructor(name){
   this.name = name
  }
 
  superPowers(){
    return {
      hello: () => {
        console.log(this.name)
      }
    }
  } 
}

const flash = new Superhero("John Wick")

console.log(flash.superPowers().hello())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This is an exercise where you have to click on a word to fill in the blanks. Every word followed by ! means I've chosen that word. I need to choose 5 words. The words I've chosen make sense to me but obviously they are incorrect